# Cannot native compile project with library that depends on okhttp

Tags: maven, ibm-cloud, graalvm, quarkus-native, key-protect

I'm currently unable to native compile one of my projects. Below you can find the related information, error and library.

Can this error be fixed on my side or it can only be fixed on library side? If that's the case, which change should be made?

- Quarkus version: 2.16.8
- Compilation "[1/7] Initializing..." info:

```cpp
 Version info: 'GraalVM 22.3.2 Java 17 CE'
 Java version info: '17.0.7+7-jvmci-22.3-b18'
 C compiler: cl.exe (microsoft, x64, 19.36.32532)
 Garbage collector: Serial GC
 9 user-specific feature(s)
 - com.oracle.svm.thirdparty.gson.GsonFeature
 - io.quarkus.caffeine.runtime.graal.CacheConstructorsFeature
 - io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.graal.DisableLoggingFeature: Disables INFO logging during the analysis phase for the [org.hibernate.Version, org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version, org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect] categories
 - io.quarkus.jdbc.postgresql.runtime.graal.SQLXMLFeature
 - io.quarkus.runner.Feature: Auto-generated class by Quarkus from the existing extensions
 - io.quarkus.runtime.graal.DisableLoggingFeature: Disables INFO logging during the analysis phase for the [org.jboss.threads] categories
 - io.quarkus.runtime.graal.ResourcesFeature: Register each line in META-INF/quarkus-native-resources.txt as a resource on Substrate VM
 - org.hibernate.graalvm.internal.GraalVMStaticFeature: Hibernate ORM's static reflection registrations for GraalVM
 - org.hibernate.graalvm.internal.QueryParsingSupport: Hibernate ORM's support for HQL Parser in GraalVM
```

- `mvnw dependency:tree` fragment:

```java
...
[INFO] +- com.ibm.cloud:ibm-key-protect-sdk:jar:0.2.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.ibm.cloud:sdk-core:jar:9.17.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:jar:3.14.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:jar:4.10.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.15:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.11.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.12.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:31.1-jre:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.google.guava:failureaccess:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.checkerframework:checker-qual:jar:3.29.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:jar:2.17.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.google.j2objc:j2objc-annotations:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:jar:2.2.21:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:jar:1.7.22:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:jar:1.7.22:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:jar:1.7.22:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common:jar:1.7.22:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.jetbrains:annotations:jar:24.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.ibm.cloud:resource-controller:jar:0.19.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.ibm.cloud:platform-services-common:jar:0.19.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.10:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:jar:3.14.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.squareup.okio:okio:jar:1.17.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.36:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.json:javax.json-api:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.glassfish:javax.json:jar:1.0.4:compile
...
```

- Error Log:

```java
Fatal error: com.oracle.graal.pointsto.util.AnalysisError$ParsingError: Error encountered while parsing com.ibm.cloud.sdk.core.http.ServiceCookieJar.saveFromResponse(okhttp3.HttpUrl, java.util.List)
Parsing context:
   at com.ibm.cloud.sdk.core.http.ServiceCookieJar.saveFromResponse(ServiceCookieJar.java:47)
   at okhttp3.internal.http.HttpHeaders.receiveHeaders(HttpHeaders.java:319)
   at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:95)
   at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142)
   at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:117)
   at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:229)
   at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:81)
   at com.ibm.cloud.sdk.core.security.TokenRequestBasedAuthenticator$2.run(TokenRequestBasedAuthenticator.java:315)
   at java.lang.Shutdown.runHooks(Shutdown.java:130)
   at java.lang.Shutdown.shutdown(Shutdown.java:185)
   at com.oracle.svm.core.jdk.RuntimeSupport.shutdown(RuntimeSupport.java:154)

        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.pointsto/com.oracle.graal.pointsto.util.AnalysisError.parsingError(AnalysisError.java:153)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.pointsto/com.oracle.graal.pointsto.flow.MethodTypeFlow.createFlowsGraph(MethodTypeFlow.java:104)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.pointsto/com.oracle.graal.pointsto.flow.MethodTypeFlow.ensureFlowsGraphCreated(MethodTypeFlow.java:83)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.pointsto/com.oracle.graal.pointsto.flow.MethodTypeFlow.getOrCreateMethodFlowsGraph(MethodTypeFlow.java:65)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.pointsto/com.oracle.graal.pointsto.typestate.DefaultVirtualInvokeTypeFlow.onObservedUpdate(DefaultVirtualInvokeTypeFlow.java:109)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.pointsto/com.oracle.graal.pointsto.flow.TypeFlow.update(TypeFlow.java:562)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.pointsto/com.oracle.graal.pointsto.PointsToAnalysis$1.run(PointsToAnalysis.java:488)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.pointsto/com.oracle.graal.pointsto.util.CompletionExecutor.executeCommand(CompletionExecutor.java:193)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.pointsto/com.oracle.graal.pointsto.util.CompletionExecutor.lambda$executeService$0(CompletionExecutor.java:177)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$RunnableExecuteAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1395)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:373)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1182)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1655)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1622)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:165)
Caused by: org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser$BytecodeParserError: com.oracle.graal.pointsto.constraints.UnresolvedElementException: Discovered unresolved method during parsing: okhttp3.internal.Internal.cookieToString(okhttp3.Cookie, boolean). This error is reported at image build time because class okhttp3.JavaNetCookieJar is registered for linking at image build time by command line
        at parsing okhttp3.JavaNetCookieJar.saveFromResponse(JavaNetCookieJar.kt:34)
        at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.throwParserError(BytecodeParser.java:2518)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.phases.SharedGraphBuilderPhase$SharedBytecodeParser.throwParserError(SharedGraphBuilderPhase.java:110)
        at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.iterateBytecodesForBlock(BytecodeParser.java:3393)
        at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.handleBytecodeBlock(BytecodeParser.java:3345)
        at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.processBlock(BytecodeParser.java:3190)
        at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.build(BytecodeParser.java:1138)
        at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.buildRootMethod(BytecodeParser.java:1030)
        at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.java.GraphBuilderPhase$Instance.run(GraphBuilderPhase.java:97)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.phases.SharedGraphBuilderPhase.run(SharedGraphBuilderPhase.java:84)
        at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.phases.Phase.run(Phase.java:49)
        at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.phases.BasePhase.apply(BasePhase.java:446)
        at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.phases.Phase.apply(Phase.java:42)
        at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.phases.Phase.apply(Phase.java:38)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.pointsto/com.oracle.graal.pointsto.flow.AnalysisParsedGraph.parseBytecode(AnalysisParsedGraph.java:135)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.pointsto/com.oracle.graal.pointsto.meta.AnalysisMethod.ensureGraphParsed(AnalysisMethod.java:685)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.pointsto/com.oracle.graal.pointsto.phases.InlineBeforeAnalysisGraphDecoder.lookupEncodedGraph(InlineBeforeAnalysis.java:180)
        at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.replacements.PEGraphDecoder.doInline(PEGraphDecoder.java:1162)
        at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.replacements.PEGraphDecoder.tryInline(PEGraphDecoder.java:1145)
        at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.replacements.PEGraphDecoder.trySimplifyInvoke(PEGraphDecoder.java:1003)
        at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.replacements.PEGraphDecoder.handleInvoke(PEGraphDecoder.java:957)
        at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.nodes.GraphDecoder.processNextNode(GraphDecoder.java:817)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.pointsto/com.oracle.graal.pointsto.phases.InlineBeforeAnalysisGraphDecoder.processNextNode(InlineBeforeAnalysis.java:240)
        at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.nodes.GraphDecoder.decode(GraphDecoder.java:548)
        at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.replacements.PEGraphDecoder.decode(PEGraphDecoder.java:833)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.pointsto/com.oracle.graal.pointsto.phases.InlineBeforeAnalysis.decodeGraph(InlineBeforeAnalysis.java:98)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.pointsto/com.oracle.graal.pointsto.flow.MethodTypeFlowBuilder.parse(MethodTypeFlowBuilder.java:179)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.pointsto/com.oracle.graal.pointsto.flow.MethodTypeFlowBuilder.apply(MethodTypeFlowBuilder.java:349)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.pointsto/com.oracle.graal.pointsto.flow.MethodTypeFlow.createFlowsGraph(MethodTypeFlow.java:93)
        ... 13 more
Caused by: com.oracle.graal.pointsto.constraints.UnresolvedElementException: Discovered unresolved method during parsing: okhttp3.internal.Internal.cookieToString(okhttp3.Cookie, boolean). This error is reported at image build time because class okhttp3.JavaNetCookieJar is registered for linking at image build time by command line
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.phases.SharedGraphBuilderPhase$SharedBytecodeParser.reportUnresolvedElement(SharedGraphBuilderPhase.java:333)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.phases.SharedGraphBuilderPhase$SharedBytecodeParser.handleUnresolvedMethod(SharedGraphBuilderPhase.java:323)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.phases.SharedGraphBuilderPhase$SharedBytecodeParser.handleUnresolvedInvoke(SharedGraphBuilderPhase.java:279)
        at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.genInvokeStatic(BytecodeParser.java:1676)
        at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.genInvokeStatic(BytecodeParser.java:1651)
        at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.processBytecode(BytecodeParser.java:5288)
        at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.iterateBytecodesForBlock(BytecodeParser.java:3385)
        ... 38 more
```

Comment: you can try to add okhttp as dependency in your pom like [here](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/discussions/28930#discussioncomment-4248575) and [here](https://quarkus.io/version/main/guides/native-reference#i-get-a-analysiserrorparsingerror-when-building-a-native-executable-due-to-an-unresolvedelementexception-what-can-i-do) says you can try link-at-build-time parameter, but over all this is ibm cloud issue you can open an issue [here](https://github.com/IBM/keyprotect-java-client/issues)

Comment: `link-at-build-time` doesn't work because it's already enabled by default. However, adding both `okttp` and `logging` from `okhttp3` on v4.10.0. I'll def. open an issue on both projects to see if they can update the dependencies.

Comment: If you want, you can write an answer so you can get the extra points ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding okhttp and logging from **okhttp3** on **v4.10.0** directly to your pom will make it compile for native binary.

According to okhttp they are preparing themself graalvm ready at okhttp 5 explained [here](https://square.github.io/okhttp/#graalvm-native-image) but your okhttp is coming from ibm-cloud therefore they need to check their dependencies and line up for **Graal**. [Here](https://github.com/IBM/keyprotect-java-client/issues) you can open the issue for them.